# Convergence in Probability is induced by a metric in $L^0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm reading some lecture notes, and the author made the following assertions:

Convergence in probability is equivalent to convergence induced by the metric $d$ defined on $L^0$ such that
$$
d(X,Y) := E\min\{|X-Y|,1\}.
$$
I'm guessing there is a typo, because it's clear that this $d$ is not a metric, since $d(X,X) = 1$. My question is if anyone would know what is the actual metric to which he is referring to, and also, what does he mean by $L^0$. Would it be the space of measurable functions?

Comment: In part, but not the part about which metric $d$ the author was intending. Or are you saying that this is the correct metric, but the author actually implied pseudo-metric?

Comment: It simply should be a $\min$, not a $\max$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_2).

Comment: @DaviBarreira: as with $L_p$'s with $p>0$, one identifies functions that differ on sets of measure $0$ and then $d$ becomes a metric in $L_0\mod 0$. The gauge $\|\;\|_0$ after identification also becomes a metric in $L_0\mod 0$.